# Sharing a url as an embedded inline video using ACTION_SEND in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

How can I embed a video url hosted in Amazon S3 , using the ACTION_SEND intent in facebook.

So far i've tried doing:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("video/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
shareIntent.putExtra("com.facebook.platform.extra.APPLICATION_ID", myAppId);
context.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"), 1234);
```

Without any success.

Answer (score 0):

The Uri needs to be a file on the local device. Otherwise you should be using a link share.

Comment: I don't want to share it from my device. We could create this "Inline Embedding" using the standard IOS Share with same links i'm trying to share with android.

Comment: Like I said, if it's an http/https link, you should use a link share, and let FB worry about how it gets presented. There's no support for the URI in a video/* share when it's not a local video. This applies for FB, for Instagram, and Youtube.